# How to read and process .fits files

Tags: c++, image-processing, astronomy

I want to work and analysis some .fits (flexible image transport system) files but I do not know what to do.

Can anybody suggest me a library for c++ to work with such files?

Answer (score 2):

You could try: [FITS++](http://www.cv.nrao.edu/adass/adassVI/farrisa.html).

But also perhaps this might be better: [CCfits](http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/fitsio/CCfits/)

Comment: I understand. However, the question was answered i.e., "Can anybody suggest a C++ library to work with FITs files". I can only answer the question.